# Make file print the output after second pass but before executing the recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to print the Makefile out after the expansion of includes.

Comment: Not really.  You can use the `-p` option to get a dump of make's internal database of rules and variables after it's read the makefile.  This can definitely be helpful during debugging, etc.  But this is not exactly the same thing as an "expanded" version of the makefile (for example, it's not like running the C/C++ compiler's preprocessor to see the output).

Comment: Sound like you are debugging makefiles -- maybe the [`remake` tool](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) can help (have not tried it myself).